# How to add newly added data from firebase to the top of the recyclerview and not at the bottom

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am making android app on `Firebase` and I want to see new data in top same as Facebook etc.

How to do to show data in my app in top when user upload new data please tell me how to do this

```
//layout recycler
recyler_view=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

#xml#


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thnku soooo much ..its awsm and easy @SantanuSur

Comment: my new data show in top but i have a prblem of design see image of my prblem my bottom data design is different @SantanuSur

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this properties to your **layoutManager**

```
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); // it will reverse the stack (bottom to top)
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); // When set to true, If RecyclerView is LTR, than it will layout from RTL
recyler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: this worked awsm @Deep

Comment: but why my bottom info design missmath from all top info

Comment: It worked then please accept the answer mate! and yes can not get your second comment

Comment: add screenshot for your design where you are having trouble.

Comment: see design screenshot by click this link https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/115839781558500443018/6537869632686280610?authkey=CLqUzZLtlfyVBw

Comment: mean???? so what to do for resolve this deisgn

Comment: can you please post XML for your design? Seems like something is there in design

Comment: see i posted xml also

Comment: Xml for the item layout is also needed mate.